# Upload file to servlet behind proxy with packet limit

Tags: java, spring, servlets, file-upload, proxy

I have an application in which file uploads are pretty common, but now we have a new scenario behind a proxy we can't control.

The proxy has a max-packet-size of 5 MB, meaning that we can only upload at most 5MB per request; and that breaks our usual 10-250 MB normal uploads.

**Is there a standard Java-based (or Spring) way to upload files on configurable chunks/parts?**

Note: From the client side (web) we planned to use [jQuery-File-Upload](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload)

Answer (score 0):

A combination of compression and chunking should work thus:

1. [Chunk your file upload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5222784/how-to-implement-http-post-chunked-upload-of-a-big-file-using-java-httpclient): This requires the server to understand/support request chunking. This will support your general need for reducing a single large packet
2. [Compress the request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1450151/can-i-compress-http-requests-using-gzip): This also requires the server to support your compression encoding

Together, both mechanisms can significantly reduce your transmission size