# How to read from file in chunks to upload in Jmeter?

Tags: java, file-upload, jmeter, beanshell, chunks

I am writing a Jmeter Test Plan to upload files to server in chunks. I've little knowledge of Java.

I've used **while controller** on **HTTP Request Sampler** with **Bean Shell Pre-Processor**. I have written a short script to get bytes from file, now the problem I am facing is: The HTTP Request Sampler takes file path in File Upload Section. Is there any way to create a file in memory in Bean Shell Pre Processor and then use that memory file variable in File Path field.

What I think is theoretically, It is possible. Because whenever we upload a file, we first take it into memory and then send to server. So, can we just create a file in memory from bytes (chunks of 1 MB) and then send it as file upload. Here is the code I've written in Bean Shell Pre-Processor

```
Integer maxChunkSize    = new Integer(vars.get("FILE_MAX_SIZE"));
String uploadFilePath   = vars.get("UPLOAD_FILE");
uploadFileSize      = new File(uploadFilePath).length();
InputStream uploadFile  = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(uploadFilePath));
int offset      = whileCounter * maxChunkSize;
ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
byte[] bytes;
int size;

/* creating bytes array to hold file data*/
if (offset < uploadFileSize) {
    if (((int) offset + (int) maxChunkSize) < uploadFileSize) {
        bytes = new byte[ (int) maxChunkSize];
        size = maxChunkSize;
    } else {
        size = (int) (uploadFileSize - offset);
        bytes = new byte[ (int) size];
        vars.put("WHILE_LOOP", "0");
    }
}

/* printing results for debugging */
/*
log.info(" ============================================================== ");
log.info("While counter " + whileCounter.toString() );
log.info("While loop " + vars.get("WHILE_LOOP").toString() );
log.info("The file to upload is : " + uploadFilePath);
log.info("Maximum Chunk size is : " + maxChunkSize.toString());
log.info("Current Offset is : " + offset.toString());
log.info("The file size is " + uploadFileSize.toString());
log.info(" ============================================================== ");
*/


/* here it is giving method invocation on loop counter 2, so skip method is used */
uploadFile.skip(offset);
int bytesRead = uploadFile.read(bytes, 0, size);


/* write to byte output stream to read as a file */
bos.write(bytes, 0, bytesRead); 


/* params for next iteration */
uploadFile.close();
whileCounter++;
vars.put("WHILE_COUNTER", whileCounter.toString() );
```

**Expected**: An alternative to upload file in chunks via JMeter **OR** Create a memory variable that will act as file for file upload path in JMeter **HTTP Request Sampler** -> **Files Upload** Section.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you can achieve this using [HTTP Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler, the options I would consider are in:

1. [Implement chunked file upload using Java code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5222784/how-to-implement-http-post-chunked-upload-of-a-big-file-using-java-httpclient) without relying onto JMeter's HTTP Request sampler, something like

   ```
   import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost
   import org.apache.http.entity.InputStreamEntity
   import org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient
   import org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClients

   CloseableHttpClient client = HttpClients.createDefault();

   HttpPost post = new HttpPost("http://example.com");
   File file = new File("/path/to/your/file");

   InputStreamEntity reqEntity = new InputStreamEntity(new FileInputStream(file), -1, "Your file mime type");

   //Alternatively:
   //FileEntity reqEntity = new FileEntity(file, "Your file mime type");

   reqEntity.setChunked(true);

   client.execute(post)
   ```
2. Go for [HTTP Raw Request](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/RawRequest/) sampler which simply sends chunked data over the wire (the size of the chunk is controllable via `kg.apc.jmeter.samplers.FileReadChunkSize` property) so you can just record the associated request body data using a sniffer tool like [Wireshark](https://wireshark.org/) and later replay it with the desired chunk size. Check out [The JMeter HTTP Raw Request Sampler - When and How to Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/the-jmeter-http-raw-request-sampler-when-and-how-to-use-it) article for more information if needed.
3. Also be aware that [since JMeter 3.1 it's recommended to use JSR223 Test Elements and Groovy language for scripting](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting) so consider migrating to Groovy on next available opportunity.